# Texture painting with a texture mask does not use the color specified

Tags: texture-painting

I can't get the texture mask to show the color when painting.

**RESULT:**

[image]

As you can see, I want to get the blue to appear when painting the texture mask on. Instead, it comes out as a black color.

Following [this tutorial here](https://youtu.be/H57IDJNeD3U?t=14m54s), I'm trying to get the color to appear on the texture mask as done there.

**GOAL:**

[image]

As well as the color changing, there is also the default TexDraw brush drawing with it too, I think. It turns the skin darker along with the texture mask.

How do I get the texture mask to have color and the same brush to change the skin color at the same time?

**EDIT:**
[image]

Comment: Could it be that you paint with Ctrl being pressed? Other than that (flipping brush colors on fly) I couldn't repeat that behaviour

Comment: Doing that did not change anything. With Ctrl and without.

Comment: Ctrl should change how the brush paints (if you hold it while painting) as it is shortcut for flipping colors (color with secondary color below the color selector) which are different in your setup. If it's possible upload the file here http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ so it's possible to take a look at other options.

Comment: I added the file, but I don't think that ctrl is the solution.

Comment: Remove Texture from the Texture rollout in the brush settings above Texture Mask one. What it was doing before was painting with tiled texture of skin and black parts between them masked with texture of skin from Texture Mask.